# SpringSecurityConfiguration - permitAll() does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to configure SpringSecurity for my application, but despite using permitAll() for one of my endpoints(/api/authorization/company-login) I keep getting 404 exceptions.
For other endpoints, I get 403 (Forbidden) which is completely right cause I also use anyRequest().authenticated(), for the others.
So it seems that while anyRequest().authenticated() works, permitAll doesn't.

I'm also sure that I put it in the right order, cause my permitAll() is before anyRequest().authenticated().

Path to the endpoint also seems right cause if I would change path in: antMatchers("/api/authorization/company-login").permitAll() for some other then for /api/authorization/company-login I'm getting 403 (what is expected in such case). I'm not sure what is wrong in my configuration and how to make /api/authorization/company-login endpoint accessible for all.

**Dependencies I use for spring security:**

```
<!-- Spring Security -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**My spring security configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private GoAuthorizationFilter goAuthorizationFilter;

    @Autowired
    private GoAuthenticationEntryPoint goAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(goAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
                .sessionManagement().and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
                .addFilterBefore(goAuthorizationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/authorization/company-login").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        return http.build();
    }
```

**Authentication Entry Point:**

```
@Component
public class GoAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

**GoAuthorizationFilter:**

```
@Service
public class GoAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Transactional
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

While I was trying to make it work I also got rid of AuthenticationEntryPoint but it seemed to have no impact. What is more my filter has no logic implemented yet, so I know that it is not the cause of my problem.

**My question is, what is wrong with my configuration, and why despite permitAll() I'm receiving 404 exceptions?**

Answer (score 0):

Error 404 means that the endpoint (/api/authorization/company-login) is not found, meaning there is no controller registered on that path mapping.

Make sure that this path is correct in your configuration and matches the controller mapping.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting 404 so it is working because 404 is for not found and 403 is for authorization . check your URL at controller first and then check output of the calling method in controller.